# Convergence sequence of random variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, normal-distribution

I have this problem about a sequence of normals.
$(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is defined as $$X_{n+1}=aX_n+U_{n+1}$$ $X_0=0$, where $(U_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a sequence of i.i.d random variable normally distributed $\mathcal{N}(m,\sigma^2)$, I have to study (for $a<1$) the convergence in distribution of $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ and tell (for $a>1$) if $$Y_n:=\frac{X_n}{a^{n-1}}$$ converges in $L^2(P)$

**What I have already done:**

I already wrote $X_n$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n a^{n-i} U_i$ and computed its mean and variance (resp $E[X_n]=m\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$ and $var[X_n]=\sigma^2 \frac{a^{2n}-1}{a^2-1}$) but now I'm stuck, the sequence $U_n$ is not even parametrized...should I simply take the limit for $n \to \infty$ of its mean and variance?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for $X_n$ is not quite right: that's actually $X_{n+1}$.

Since the question talks about convergence in distribution, you do want to take limits as $n \to \infty$.  Note that a sum of independent normal random variables is normal.

Comment: true, thanks for make me noticing...can you help me with the second part? I know I have to prove $$E[(Y_n-Y)^2] \to 0$$ I already computed $E[Y_n^2]$ and $E[Y^2]$, but what about $E[Y_n Y]$? My problem is in particular the covariance...

ps I edited the second part of the question

Comment: Still not quite right.  If it's $X_{n+1} = a X_n + U_n$, you should have $X_1 = U_0$, $X_2 = a U_0 + U_1$, etc.
Anyway, there's no $Y$: for $a > 1$ you have $E[Y_n] = a^{-n+1} E[X_n]$ and $\text{Var}(Y_n) = a^{-2n+2} \text{Var}(X_n)$.  What are the limits of those as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Sorry, it was anyway $U_{n+1}$...anyway, my problem is when I plug $a^{1-a}$ in the previous $E[X_n]$ and $var[X_n]$ (but now $a>1$) I don't get $0$, but $E[Y]=\frac{a}{a-1}m$ and $var[Y]=\sigma^2\frac{a^2}{a^2-1}$

Comment: OK, so for $a > 1$ we find that $Y_n$ converges in distribution to a nontrivial normal r.v.  Now look at
$\text{Cov}(X_n, X_m)$ and $\text{Cov}(Y_n, Y_m)$ for $n > m$.

Comment: I'm trying but seems impossible to find a unique formula...I found $$\sum_{i=1}^m a^{2(n-i)}var[U_i]$$ works for $m$ even, and $$\sum_{i=1}^m a^{2(n-i)-1} var[U_i]$$ for $m$ odd...I mean $cov(X_n,X_m)$ (then I'll plug $\frac{1}{a^{n-1}}$ inside)

Comment: not even, because $$cov(X_4,X_1) =a^5var[U_1]$$ while it should have been $a^3$...

Comment: It seems the coefficients follow the following structure:$cov(X_1,X_4),cov(X_2,X_4),cov(X_3,X_4),cov(X_4,X_4),cov(X_5,X_4)...$
          $$a^3$$
      $$a^4 a^2$$
     $$a^5  a^3 a^1$$
    $$a^6 a^4 a^2 a^0$$
  $$a^7 a^5 a^3 a^1 a^{-1}$$
$$a^8 a^6 a^4 a^2 a^0 a^{-2} $$

(and the negative coefficients have to be discarded...so that, for instance, in this case the last term is always $var[U_4]$, as it should)

Comment: For $n > m$,  $X_n = a^{n-m} X_m + $(something independent of $X_m$), so $\text{Cov}(X_n, X_m) = a^{n-m} \text{Var}(X_m)$.

Comment: thanks, I was trying the "inductive" procedure, like I did the on the first part but it seemed incredibly difficult to take a general rule...anyway, I see where we're going, but I have still some difficulties...I plugged inside $\frac{1}{a^{n-1}}$ and $\frac{1}{a^{m-1}}$, getting $$Cov(Y_n,Y_m)=a^{-2m+2}Var(X_m)$$ since this limit does not depend on $n$ I would conclude $cov(Y,Y_n)$ is simply $$a^{-2n+2}Var(X_n)$$
is that correct?